# How to paginate django queryset by field effectively?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-pagination

I have a model with a `Boolean` field, and I want to paginate the query set of this model by the `Boolean` field with the rule:

1. Page size is 10
2. Each page contain 2 items whose `Boolean` field is
   `True` and 8 items whose `Boolean` field is `False`
3. If one page can not satisfy rule 2, such as there are remaining items with `False` value after pagination, just append them to page

For example:

With the `Food` model, I want every page has 2 fat food and 8 non-fat food

```
class Food(models.Model):
    # whether fat food 
    is_fat_food = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # other field
```

Now, I implement the pagination with the following algorithm in `get_queryset`. BTW, I use `ListModelMixin` in my interface to implement pagination.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    fat_food_qs = Food.objects.filter(is_fat_food=True)
    non_fat_food_qs = Food.objects.filter(is_fat_food=False)
    final_qs = []
    fat_page_size = 2
    no_fat_page_size = 8
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(fat_food_qs) and j < len(non_fat_food_qs):
        if i + fat_page_size > len(fat_food_qs):
            break
        if j + no_fat_page_size > len(non_fat_food_qs):
            break
        final_qs += fat_food_qs[i:i+fat_page_size]
        final_qs += non_fat_food_qs[j:j+non_fat_food_qs]
        i += fat_page_size
        j += non_fat_food_qs
    # remaining food no need to obey the rule, just append
    if i < len(fat_food_qs):
        final_qs += fat_food_qs[i:]
    if j < len(non_fat_food_qs):
        final_qs += non_fat_food_qs[j:]
    return final_qs
```

By this algorithm, I get the right and expected result, but I think it is not efficient.

Because default pagination algorithm based on query set use  lazy-loading mechanism which just load one specific page when request that page.

But in my algorithm, I need to traverse and handle the query set before pagination.

I am a freshman in django and I don't know whether I need to implement a pagination without using `ListModelMixin`, just based on the request parameter `page` and `page_size` to get the specific page query result and construct the `prev` and `next` page link in response.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

PS: I am also a freshman in python, If any codes are not pythonic, please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/) available in django core.

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
import itertools

page_size1 = 2
page_size2 = 8
queryset_obj1 = Food.objects.filter(is_fat_food=True)
queryset_obj2 = Food.objects.filter(is_fat_food=False)

data1 = Paginator(queryset_obj1, page_size).page(page_number).object_list 
data2 = Paginator(queryset_obj2, page_size).page(page_number).object_list     
merged = list(itertool.chain(data1, data2))  # merged is a list containing Food objects.
```

The solution above won't be much optimum than provided in answer for very less db rows but it would perform better for large data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know `paginator`. In my opinion, standard `paginator` can not implement my requirement.

Comment: You should read my question more carefully. I want to implement pagination based on `model field` more efficiently.  Now I implemented `get_queryset` method is based on `paginator`. The point is the query set can not be easily given by `model.objects.all()`.

Comment: see the edit this would be more maintainable solution without using much heuristics

Comment: Thanks again.  This solution is good. Frankly I think about it before. But two query set may do not have same pages.  In this case,  the query set with more pages need fill the full page.  Also it is not easy to construct the `next` and `prev` page link.

Comment: The queryset will always have same page your solution and solution above will provide same result always and that is for sure, data is always indexed and filter will always give results in same order.

Comment: Do you think about `4 fat food` with `80 non-fat food`?

Comment: it will give null for fat food after 2 pages. But that's the rest designs. In this case what output do you expect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147468/discussion-between-fogmoon-and-arpit-solanki).